# Quickfix support for Python tracebacks

Tags: quickfix, filetype-python, makeprg

Say I have a python script with a runtime error:

```
$ cat example.py  
#! /usr/bin/env python3

a = 1/0
```

which gives:

```
$ python3 example.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 3, in <module>
    a = 1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

I want Vim to jump to the problematic line of that file (line 3 in this case). I know Vim can do this because it works just fine for catching errors at compile time in C with `gcc` using `:make` and the `quickfix` window.

[image: quickfix output from gcc]

Sure, I can populate Vim's quickfix window with `:set makeprg=python3\ %` and then `:make`, but it does not jump to the line number where the traceback points to. When I look in `:copen` it just highlights the first line of the trace, and I can't jump to the relevant line number.

[image: quickfix output from python3]

(I'm using Vim 7.4  on Debian `jessie` in case that matters.)

My questions are:

- Can I configure Vim so that it knows how to get the relevant line number from a Python traceback?
- Can I modify the Python interpreter to spit out an error format that Vim already knows how to parse and get the relevant line number?

Comment: You could subclass the logger in your script to produce traceback points one per line (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180159/how-do-i-can-format-exception-stacktraces-in-python-logging) to get started), then adjust `errorformat` accordingly and write a compiler plugin for Vim (see `:help :compiler` and `:help write-compiler-plugin`).  Probably not worth the effort if you don't know _exactly_ what you're doing and you're not enthusiastic enough to dig everything out from the docs.

Comment: I asked a similar question on StackOverflow, you may find those answers useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333112/how-can-i-send-line-number-from-python-traceback-into-vim

Comment: Reddit [View Python traceback as quickfix](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/60lics/view_python_traceback_as_quickfix/) recommends Tim Pope's [Vim-Dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) package. `:Dispatch python3  %` will return the output of the current script as a quick fix window.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vim comes with a set of "compiler" scripts, one of which is called ["pyunit"](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#compiler-pyunit).  If you run `:compiler pyunit` and then `:make` (with your suggested value for `'makeprg'`), quickfix is populated as you expect.  However, it only works well if there's one level to the stack trace.

Improving that compiler script would be a useful exercise.

The [unstack](https://github.com/mattboehm/vim-unstack) plugin may be of interest, as it provides a general mechanism to parse and view the locations reported in a stack trace and has Python support built in.

Answer (score 14):

## Built in compiler plugin `pyunit`

As already suggested by [jamessan](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10147/17998), one option is to use the built in compiler plugin `pyunit`:

```
:compiler pyunit
:set makeprg=python3\ %
:make
```

This has the downside, that it collapses the stack trace to a single error message. For example the following python script:

```
def lumberjack():
    bright_side_of_death()

def bright_side_of_death():
    return tuple()[0]

lumberjack()
```

... produces this error message:

```
|| Traceback (most recent call last):
lumberjack.py|7|  IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

## Writing your own compiler plugin

As an alternative, you can provide your own compiler plugin in
`~/.vim/compiler/python.vim`:

```
if exists("current_compiler")
  finish
endif
let current_compiler = "python"

let s:cpo_save = &cpo
set cpo&vim

CompilerSet errorformat=
      \%*\\sFile\ \"%f\"\\,\ line\ %l\\,\ %m,
      \%*\\sFile\ \"%f\"\\,\ line\ %l,
CompilerSet makeprg=python3\ %

let &cpo = s:cpo_save
unlet s:cpo_save
```

Select the plugin manually with `:compiler python`, or load it automatically by adding this to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`:

```
if !exists("current_compiler")
  compiler python
endif
```

With the python script from above, Vim populates the quickfix window with:

```
|| Traceback (most recent call last):
lumberjack.py|7| in <module>
||     lumberjack()
lumberjack.py|2| in lumberjack
||     bright_side_of_death()
lumberjack.py|5| in bright_side_of_death
||     return tuple()[0]
|| IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

See [`:help write-compiler-plugin`](https://vimhelp.org/usr_51.txt.html#write-compiler-plugin) for more information.

Comment: What's up with the `cpo_save`?

Comment: @CervEd `cpo_save` and `set cpo&vim` is boilerplate code used in most plugins. It's there to disable Vi compatibility for the duration of this script. For example a user might have line continuation disabled ([:help cpo-C](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#cpo-C)), so this plugin would fail when setting `errorformat`.

Answer (score 4):

[quickfix.py](https://github.com/tonyxty/quickfix.py) parses the traceback into a vim-friendly errorformat. Here is an example of running it on a file with a single line `1 / 0`.

```
❯❯❯ quickfix.py tests/errors/div_by_zero.py
"tests/errors/div_by_zero.py":1: ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

By default, it shows user files, but it can show system files too (running it on a file containing `import os; os.environ['123']`):

```
❯❯❯ quickfix.py -a /tmp/test.py                                                                                                        
"/usr/lib/lib/python3.7/os.py":678: KeyError: '123'
"/tmp/test.py":1: in function <module>
```

## Configuration:

When `quickfix.py` is available in the current path, add the following lines in the vimrc to use it.

```
if has("autocmd")
  autocmd FileType python setlocal makeprg=quickfix.py\ %
  autocmd FileType python setlocal errorformat=%E\"%f\":%l:%m,
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an automatic method but the python Traceback states the line number --- 3 in your example --- and so invoking vim:

`$ vim +3 example.py`

will open the `example.py` with the cursor on the third line.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but this is about Quickfix support. After I've run `:make` on a file I've already got open, it's faster to use `:3` to jump to the third line than to close and re-open. Also, doing this manually is a pain for more complex stack traces, which is why I want Quickfix support.