# Improve `gf` such that it would jump to the exact line, if possible

Tags: navigation, python

If a path is written in form `filepath:line` (i.e. python exception), I want `gf` to jump straight to the line.

Comment: If it's a Python exception, you should look in to using the quickfix list. See also: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5110/205

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want already exists: `:help gF`.

Note that `gF` behaves like `gf` in the absence of a line number so you can default to `gF` if you don't want to think too much about which command to use in which case.

--- EDIT ---

Note that Python exceptions are actually in the form:

```
File "/path/to/file", line 10, in <module>
```

where the `"` and the `,` between the filename and `line 1` trip Vim's algorithm. `gF` works fine for `/path/to/filename:10` but not for every scenario.

Comment: Since `:` is part of ìsfname` on Windows (looks like a bug), to make it working you have to remove it first `:set isfname-=:`

Comment: This is not a bug, because you may have file paths with a drive letter

Comment: Thanks @Christian but then the solution should include mention the setting change to meet the original requirement.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt, the suggestion of removing `:` from `isfname` is not a good idea, for the reason given by @ChristianBrabandt. It could be done temporarily in a wrapper but that's really not the spirit of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the implementation.
I haven't completed it for vmap, though not complicated.

I didn't check it is really a line number, so be careful.

```
function! DoGF()
    let f=expand('<cfile>')
    let arr=split(f,':')
    if len(arr)>1
        if  filereadable(expandcmd(arr[0]))==0
            echoerr "File not exists"
            return
        endif
        :exe ':e '.arr[0]
        :exe ':'.arr[1]
    else
       norm! gf 
    endif
endfunction

nmap gf :call DoGF()<CR>
```